# "Redirect url" error in facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on facebook api. I want to get all facebook post of a user. I have set the app_id, secret and permission in my code.

This code is working on my localhost perfectly. but when I am putting it on server then during authentication it is giving error :

> This webpage has a redirect loop

My code is located at the url : https://github.com/ucerturohti/facebookapitest.git

and the app is located at https://statusupdates.herokuapp.com

**update**

When I am putting redirect url "https://statusupdates.herokuapp.com" then its authenticating.

but when I put redirect url as "https://statusupdates.herokuapp.com/getlike.php" then it is giving error.

**update 2**

When I am trying to echo the value of $user, it is always giving 0

Comment: Under your app's settings, what do you have the Site URL set to? Is it configured for your Heroku app?

Comment: under site url I have put https://statusupdates.herokuapp.com

Comment: this application is working on localhost perfectly, giving error on the server only

Answer (score 0):

Do not put header() inside constructor...
it will always send you to login page when you instantiate facebookAllInOne class

Comment: so how to redirect to login page then ?

Comment: There are some problems with facebook sdk for PHP. you better use Javascript SDK for login & to fetch data.